# no user matches the given query while using username as an argument

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

Till now i have been using userid's `(pk)` as an argument in the profile urls for my application. Recently i decided to use the `username` instead of the user id's So i changed the following :

### Urls.py

```
# This was what i was using previously
url(r'^profile/(?P<uid>\d+)/$', 'app.views.user_profile', name="profile"),

# Changed the above to this.
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)/$', 'app.views.user_profile', name="profile"),
```

### Views.py

```
# Previous view
@login_required
def user_profile(request, uid):

    user = get_object_or_404(models.User, pk=uid)
    profile = helpers.get_profile(user)
    render_to_response('profile.html', {'profile' : profile})


# Changed the above to
@login_required
def user_profile(request, username):

    user = get_object_or_404(models.User, username=username)
    profile = helpers.get_profile(user)
    render_to_response('profile.html', {'profile' : profile})
```

Until Now it's all good. When i try to visit `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/some_username/` instead of the previous `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/some_number/` it works fine.

I have a toolbar in the `profile.html`, which contains links such as:

```
/profile/edit/
/profile/settings/
```

in the `urls.py` these urls map to very simple views. Such as the following.

```
@login_required
def profile_settings(request):
    """  
    This view helpers.renders the profile's settings panel
    """
    print 'hello'
    rec, can = helpers.get_user_or_noprofile(request.user)
    if not can is None:
        gform = forms.CandidateGeneralSettingsForm(instance=can)
        jsform = forms.CandidateJobSearchSettingsForm(instance=can)
        data = {'candidate' : can, 'gform' : gform, 'jsform' : jsform }
    else:
        form = forms.RecruiterSettingsForm(instance=rec)
        data = { 'recruiter' : rec, 'form' : form }
    return helpers.render(request, 'profile_settings.html', data)
```

The weird part is after i changed to use `username` in the profile url. As soon as i click on any of the links in the toolbar, i see the `404 : Error : No User matches the given query.` page.

To debug i tried printing a few debug statements within these views and found out something more weird. Nothing gets printed even if i Comment the whole code inside the view and just write a print statement.

This makes me doubt that the problem might be with the `login_required` decorator. but if that's the case howcome it is working while visitng `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/some_username/`.

I really can't think of anything that might be causing this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

PS: Also, JFYI, i am using a custom Email Authentication backend that lets user login through their email address instead of the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because `edit` is not a valid username.

This url `/profile/edit/` matches `^profile/(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)/$`, and `username` becomes `edit`.

Since you don't have a user called "edit", this `user = get_object_or_404(models.User, username=username)` fails, and raises a `404`.

The same for `/profile/settings/`.

Comment: Damn, that was quick! and wow yeah it makes sense now, Thanks!